# Need to get a string after a "word" in a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, substring

i'm having a string in c# for which i have to find a specific word "code" in the string and have to get the remaining string after the word "code".

The string is

> "Error description, **code** : -1"

so i have to find the word **code** in the above string and i have to get the error code.
I have seen regex but now clearly understood. Is there any simple way ?

Comment: What would happen should `code` appear twice in said string?

Comment: Can you clarify - what's the issue with regex?  What have you tried and what code do you currently have?

Comment: @LukeHennerley code may appear twice or more, but at the end, the error code definition will be **code: error code**

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
string toBeSearched = "code : ";
string code = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(toBeSearched) + toBeSearched.Length);
```

Something like this?

Perhaps you should handle the case of missing `code :`...

```
string toBeSearched = "code : ";
int ix = myString.IndexOf(toBeSearched);

if (ix != -1) 
{
    string code = myString.Substring(ix + toBeSearched.Length);
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 22):

```
var code = myString.Split(new [] {"code"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
// code = " : -1"
```

You can tweak the string to split by - if you use `"code : "`, the second member of the returned array (`[1]`) will contain `"-1"`, using your example.

Comment: Split only takes `params[] char`, it doesn't take `params[] string` :)

Comment: @LukeHennerley - [Really?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Comment: I was meant to say this doesn't compile :P I stand corrected!

Comment: @LukeHennerley - The simplest overload only takes `params char[]`. All the `string[]` overloads require additional parameters.

Answer (score 15):

Simpler way (if your only keyword is "code" ) may be:

```
string ErrorCode = yourString.Split(new string[]{"code"}, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
```

Comment: @LukeHennerley it is very common approach for initializing array of strings

Answer (score 11):

add this code to your project

```
  public static class Extension {
        public static string TextAfter(this string value ,string search) {
            return  value.Substring(value.IndexOf(search) + search.Length);
        }
  }
```

then use

```
"code : string text ".TextAfter(":")
```

Answer (score 3):

use `indexOf()` function

```
string s = "Error description, code : -1";
int index = s.indexOf("code");
if(index != -1)
{
  //DO YOUR LOGIC
  string errorCode = s.Substring(index+4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string founded = FindStringTakeX("UID:   994zxfa6q", "UID:", 9);


string FindStringTakeX(string strValue,string findKey,int take,bool ignoreWhiteSpace = true)
    {
        int index = strValue.IndexOf(findKey) + findKey.Length;

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            if (ignoreWhiteSpace)
            {
                while (strValue[index].ToString() == " ")
                {
                    index++;
                }
            }

            if(strValue.Length >= index + take)
            {
                string result = strValue.Substring(index, take);

                return result;
            }


        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string originalSting = "This is my string";
string texttobesearched = "my";
string dataAfterTextTobeSearch= finalCommand.Split(new string[] { texttobesearched     }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
if(dataAfterTextobeSearch!=originalSting)
{
    //your action here if data is found
}
else
{
    //action if the data being searched was not found
}
```