# how to get a word after another in an array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am in need of searching through an array looking for a key word and obtain the word right after that. Something like this but in c [Need to get a string after a "word" in a string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998595/need-to-get-a-string-after-a-word-in-a-string-in-c-sharp). I thought about using strtok but it will destroy the array from the tokenizing and I need read without messing with the array. Is there any way I can do this?

```
array[50] = "Hi, I am victor";
// I want the word after the "am" without destroying or messing up the array
```

Comment: Why not just make a copy if the array before using the destructive call? If you know that will get the job done?

Comment: I haven't tried this on C but when I did a copy in arduino, the back up array still got messed with without me ever touching it. Maybe I did something wrong but that experience made me kind of not want to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Use strstr().

```
char* am = strstr( array , "am " ) ;
char* next_word = NULL ;
if( am )
    next_word = am + strlen( "am ") ;
```

The last line will move the pointer to the position of the word after the "am ".

This assumes all words are separated by a single space and nothing else. You might want to check for other characters and multiple spaces. I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtok, you just need to copy the string to a temp string before handing it to strtok:

```
char array[50] = "Hi, I am victor";
char tmp[50];
char tokensep[] = " \n\r"; 
char *tok_ptr;

snprintf(tmp,50,"%s",array);

token = strtok_r(tmp, tokensep, &tok_ptr);  
while(token != NULL & strcmp(token,"am") != 0)
{
    token = strtok_r(NULL, tokensep, &tok_ptr); 
}
token = strtok_r(NULL, tokensep, &tok_ptr); 
// token now contains the name
```