# asp.net find substring Indexof

Tags: asp.net, substring

I need to get 2 substrings S1 and S2 before and after @@token@@ from the following string

```
Token = 15d7b736-d8f0-e711-b842-100ba9d19b04@@token@@131599776034855065

'/// To Get S1
S1 = Token.Substring(0, Token.IndexOf("@@token@@"))
```

S1 will be '15d7b736-d8f0-e711-b842-100ba9d19b04'

but I'm not sure how to get S2? 
S2 should be '131599776034855065'

Any help :)

Comment: `Token.IndexOf("foo") + "foo".Length`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to get a string after a "word" in a string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998595/need-to-get-a-string-after-a-word-in-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
string s = "15d7b736-d8f0-e711-b842-100ba9d19b04@@token@@131599776034855065";
string str1 = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("@"));
string str2 = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("@")+1, s.Length -1 - s.LastIndexOf("@"));
```

Or another way is splitting the string based on `@@token@@`:

```
string[] strArr = s.Split(new string[] { "@@token@@" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

`str[0]="15d7b736-d8f0-e711-b842-100ba9d19b04"`

And

`str[1]="131599776034855065"`

Note:

To split string based string you should use split string array overload.

Comment: The OP did not specify whether "S2" could contain an `@`.

Comment: @CodeCaster, No that is because of `+1` I edited seed know.

Comment: I mean if `131599776034855065` instead were `1315997760@4855065` the first part of your answer will not do what the OP requested.

Comment: @CodeCaster I know, but he mentioned he want to split based on `@@token@@`, anyway you are right thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `lastIndexOf()` method to get.

```
string Token = "15d7b736-d8f0-e711-b842-100ba9d19b04@@token@@131599776034855065";
string delimiter = "@@token@@";
string S1 = Token.Substring(0, Token.IndexOf(delimiter));
string S2 = Token.Substring(Token.LastIndexOf(delimiter) + delimiter.Length, Token.Length - delimiter.Length - S1.Length );
Console.WriteLine(S1); // or print(s1)
Console.WriteLine(S2); //or print(s2)
```